# Why speed of sound in gas depends on density but not pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, waves, pressure, acoustics, density

The book tells that with decrease in density there is an increase in speed of sound in gas but with increase in pressure there is no change in the speed of sound in gas. Why?

If pressure increases then density should have increase therefore by formula $$V = \sqrt{\frac{γP}{d}}$$ the speed of sound in gas should have remained constant even when density is increased as the increased density should have resulted in an increased pressure.

So I am confused that in case of pressure it's written that when pressure increases the density increases in such a way that $\frac{P}{p}$ remains constant therefore there is no change in speed but in case of density it's not the same.

Comment: "The book" (which one) appears to be wrong.  From your formula (which is correct) sound speed depens only on the temperature $T$.

Answer (score 3):

The variables are related by the ideal gas equation $pV=nRT$. We can write $n = m/M$ where $m$ is the mass of the gas and $M$ is its molar mass. Therefore we have
$$pV=nRT \\ pV=\frac{m}{M}RT \\ p = \frac{m}{V} \frac{RT}{M} = \frac{\rho RT}{M}$$
The equation for speed can also be written as $$v = \sqrt{\frac{\gamma RT}{M}}$$
Your statements depend on what variable(s) you hold constant.

$p$ and $\rho$ are directly proportional to each other only if both $T$ and $M$ are constant.

Changing $\rho$ without affecting $p$ and $T$ means changing the $M$ of the gas (which is essentially changing the gas itself). In this case, the speed of sound will change.

Comment: Is there a logical answer for this ? By logical I mean that ,can this be understood without theoretical physics?

Comment: @Raghav I don't understand what you mean, and I think the answer would be no.